# tokenize and parse concurrently

Tags: c++, parsing, visual-c++, c++17, ppl

Given the new c++17 standard is bringing in more flexibility to concurrency and std::feature and tasks in particular. I was wondering if I can use the "tasks" (I'm using Microsoft implementation, ppl) to do some kind of concurrent Parsing and Tokenize (which includes async read from file too). I was following a model similar to that was discussed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2012/05/09/how-to-put-a-ppltasks-continuation-chain-into-a-loop/) with regards to read/write in an async fashion (without the use of the create_iterative_task utility)..

```
Concurrency::task<void> buildParseTree(Parser p, Tokenizer t)
{
    return t.asyncEmit()
        .then([&p](Token token) {return p.asyncParse(token); })
        .then([&t, &p]() {
        if (t.done() == true) {
            return Concurrency::task_from_result();
        }
        else {
            return buildParseTree((p), (t));
        }
    });
}
```

using this as:

```
Concurrency::task<void> ts = buildParseTree(p, t);
ts.get();
```

when we do `get` it actually triggers the rest of the tasks and the parse tree is incrementally being built in the Parser.. once `get` returns, we should have the parse tree (in case parsing succeeds)..

- does this model make sense when reading a file, tokenizing and parsing a huge file.
- am I using the "infra" correctly ? would it make more sense to use `&&`  semantics? essentially how would one expose this API to the users. Code review for this snippet would be great.. I know its not complete code, but just this piece syntax and semantics of it.

Comment: Could work, but you should investigate on the overhead. For some task/future libraries a `.then()` would schedule a continuation on a specific scheduler or even another thread. If you do that for each token that you have parsed that would be quite a lot of overhead.